# swift - I can connect to socket.io server but I can't emit event

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, xcode, sockets

I am beginner to socket.io
now I can connect to socket server & server log my connection
but I can't emit events to the server 
here is my code :

```
 let socket =  SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://xxxxxxx:3000")!)
    socket.connect()
     let username = "yay"
    socket.emit("add", username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved the problem :

```
socket.on("connect")
        {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")



            socket.emit("chat message",myJSON)

        }
```